# Cloud SQL memory leak after upgrading from 13.8 to Postgres 13.10

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

After upgrading from 13.8 to 13.10 (Cloud SQL Postgres) it seems that the memory usage drastically changed. Does anyone had a similar situation ?

[image]

We then decided to increase the memory from 60 to 90Gi to understand if we were seeing the same pattern and it seems to be same.

[image]

Comment: That's not necessarily a memory leak, just a big jump in usage. You'll need much more detailed measurements if you want to pin down why (or talk to Google). I don't think Google publish what changes they make to the PostgreSQL source, so it's going to be difficult for anyone else.

Comment: thanks for the answer @RichardHuxton, I currently have a ticket open, they acknowledged the problem and are currently working on it since Monday. I was wondering if someone had similar issue from other cloud provider. Also updated the issue after trying to increase the memory and seeing exactly the same pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @RichardHuxton! I would suggest to post your ticket as an answer as this may be helpful for other community members with similar concerns.

Comment: Added a new screenshot of the total memory usage after a week and still following the same memory leak trend and still no advance on GCP side. This is pretty scary.